# FadeIn a part of an Ajax snippet with dojo

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, dojo

I want to reload bits of a page and fadein parts of that using dojo. Now the problem is, once I insert the `innerHTML` after it loads, everything becomes visible right away. I'll try to explain:

```
function reload(page) {
   var sliderBox = dojo.byId("slider_box");
   var xhrArgs = {
     url: "/myhtmlsnippet.html",
     load: function(data) {
        dojo.fadeOut({
            duration:100,
            node:sliderBox,
            onEnd:function() {
                dojo.byId('slides_container').innerHTML = data;
                dojo.fadeIn({
                    duration:400,
                    node:sliderBox,
                    onEnd:slideRotate()
                }).play();
            }
        }).play();
     }
  }
  var ajax = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
}
```

`slider_box` is a child of `slides_container`. I want to fade out `slider_box`, reload `slides_container` with `slider_box` *staying* hidden, and then fade in `slider_box`.
I tried setting `slider_box` to `visibility:hidden` via CSS but that way it never fades in.
So, can anyone help me out here?

Comment: can you show the html code at start, and what is transmitted in "/myhtmlsnippet.html"'s data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you fade out the node #slider_box. So its opacity fall to 0.

Then, you **replace** that node by some new content. There will still be a #slider_box after instruction:

```
dojo.byId('slides_container').innerHTML = data
```

but that would be a new node, which opacity hasn't been touched.

So its fully visible and the fadeIn operation will animate its opacity from 1 to 1, in other words it will do nothing.

You must set opacity to 0 and/or visibility to hidden (don't know how dojo animations work) just after the innerHTML instructions.
edit:or better, set opacity to 0 befire in your html template you're calling.

Plus, the sliderBox variable you pass as node: argument to fadeIn refers to, as I said earlier, a node you wiped out by replacing in with your innerHTML statement.

You must lookup up again to the new node like this:

```
node:dojo.byId("slider_box"),
```

in conclusion, innerHTML is the source of all javascript evil (after ie, of course).

Comment: Thanks! "You must lookup up again to the new node like this:", that solved my problem!